# How can I get rid of this white space underneath my body without using overflow-y: hidden?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the page fit in the full view of a web browser, but for some reason, I am being left with white space beneath the body. The reason I have added height is that without a height, it doesn't align vertically with flex.

I want to be able to address this without hiding the overflow-y as that doesn't seem to work well with the responsive code.

I have tried making the body and HTML 100%, which was preventing me from vertically aligning the container.

The page is on Github if you wish to see it there. Where you will see a white space beneath everything:
http://kaleshe.co.uk/portfolio

Here is a snippet of the main HTML I have been checking whilst testing:

```
<body>...
<header>...</header>
<main>
    <div class="container" id="index">
      <section>
        <h1>Web Designer in London</h1>
        <h2>I create beautiful websites that are easy to use on mobile and desktop.</h2>
        <a href="work.html"><button class="btn-dark">View Work</button></a>
      </section>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>...
```

Here is some of the relevant CSS:

```
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: var(--secondary-colour);
  background: linear-gradient(130deg, var(--main-colour) 0%,  var(--main-colour) 20%, #000a18 100%);
  background-image: url('../img/city.svg'), linear-gradient(130deg, var(--main-colour) 0%,  var(--main-colour) 20%, #000a18 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 100%;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

main {
  height: calc(100% - 2em);
}
```

I expect for there to be no white space anywhere. But there is currently whitespace

Answer (score 1):

In the linked page, the default margin (set by the user agent stylesheet) of the `<ul>` element used for the nav is offsetting your `<main>` element, which creates the white space.
Depending on your preference, you can either remove the default margin of `<ul>` with or adjust the size of your `<main>`.

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
}
/* or */
main {
  height: calc(100% - 4em);
}
```

Comment: the actual cause is the user agent stylesheet, which assigns any `ul` with `margin-block-start: 1em;` and `margin-block-end: 1em;`, adding additional `2em`s.

Answer (score 0):

If i got you correct then

Try these Changes and Update the me by comment

**Change 1**

```
body{
   //remove this below padding
   padding: 1em;
   padding: 1em 1em 0 1em; //add this 
 }
```

**Change 2**

```
main{
   height: calc(100% - 2em); //remove this one also
 }
```

Try to add this i think this will solve the problem

**Change 3**

```
body{
   //remove bottom padding only
   padding: 1em 1em 0 1em; //add this 
 }
```

Comment: When I remove these it prevents the vertical align. Is there a way I can still vertically align it without these there?

Comment: @KalesheAlleyne-Vassel  try the **change 3** i think that what you want.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will work for you.

```
main {
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: I forgot to clarify that I need the main to have a height so I can vertically align the container. Without a height, it springs to the top

Comment: Please use this
main {
    height: calc(100% - 81px - .5em);
}

Comment: This works! Thank you :) How did you come up with that math if you don't mind me asking?

Comment: first get padding of body tag and get half of 1em then get header tag height which will be 81.6px and i made it 81px then calculate.

Answer (score 0):

you are adding a `padding` to body aside `height:100%`. body is 100% height + the vertical `padding`.

You need to reset `box-sizing`(on `body` , usuallyreset is on everything via `*` ), so padding is included in height calculation:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing
>
> The `box-sizing` CSS property defines how the user agent should calculate the total `width` and `height` of an element.

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: var(--secondary-colour);
  background: linear-gradient(130deg, var(--main-colour) 0%, var(--main-colour) 20%, #000a18 100%);
  background-image: url('../img/city.svg'), linear-gradient(130deg, var(--main-colour) 0%, var(--main-colour) 20%, #000a18 100%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 100%;
  line-height: 1.7em;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;  /* !!!!!!!!!!!!  Update !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! */
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
}

main {
  height: 100%;  /* !!!!!!!!!!!!  Update !!!!!!!!!!!!!!! */
}


/* show center */
html {
background:linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2)50%),linear-gradient(90deg, transparent 50%, rgba(0,0,0,0.2)50%);
```

```html
<main>
  <div class="container" id="index">
    <section>
      <h1>Web Designer in London</h1>
      <h2>I create beautiful websites that are easy to use on mobile and desktop.</h2>
      <a href="work.html"><button class="btn-dark">View Work</button></a>
    </section>
  </div>
</main>
```

Note: no need to mind the `padding` anymore on `main`'s `height` once it is included via `box-sizing`

Comment: @KalesheAlleyne-Vassel ?? what is the trouble ?

Comment: Although I did that it seems the header is the culprit in making the body extend but I don't quite understand how when it's inside of the body